# How to get options id in other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I've the following code:

```
this.showNotificationcenter = function () {
    centerNotification =
        $("<div class='notificationbar'> <h2>Notificaties</h2>" +
        "<ul></ul></div>");
    var fullPage = $(document).find("#fullPage");
    fullPage.append(centerNotification);
}

this.center = function (options) {
    var notificationsUl = $(centerNotification).find("ul");
    notification = $("<li id="+options.id+"><b>" + options.title + "<span class='fa fa-times'></span></b><br />" + options.content + "</li>");
    notificationsUl.append(notification);
}

this.removeLi = function () {
    var test = $(notification).find("id").val();
}
```

And I use this code to create a notification:

```
    eformity.notification.center({
        title: "Dit is een titel",
        content: "Dit is een content",
        id: "een",
    });
```

I need to get the options.id in the function removeLi but I've no idea how to. (var test is now undefined) Eventually, I need a click event on the span which will delete that Li. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c10gasbL/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using `attr` to find the value of the attribute id.

```
var test = $(notification).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Id

var test=$(notification).attr('id');

To replace Id

var test=$(notification).attr('id', 'newId');